# Spring Security 3 Namespace Configuration Gotcha

Tags: configuration, namespaces, spring-security

Hi
I am not able to understand why am I getting the following error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: You cannot use a spring-security-2.0.xsd schema with Spring Security 3.0. Please update your schema declarations to the 3.0 schema.

when I try to run my application having following security namespace configuration:

Security configuration:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd
 ">
...
</beans:beans>
```

Could someone help me understand it please?

Thanks

Comment: What exact versions of Spring and Spring Security are you using?

Comment: Hi skaffman, I've got it resolved by changing the jars from version 3.0.0 to 3.0.5. I was under the impression that I was using 3.0.5 version only. Many thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Hi, I've got the same problem, do you mean you use 3.0.5 for both spring framework and spring security?

Comment: @david99world: Yes, I used `3.0.5` version both for spring and spring security with this application.